# How to find only the total RAM in Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, command

I am creating a bunch of Python functions for use in a later script and they find things like free RAM, Total RAM, and RAM in use. I want to only find the number, nothing else. Is there a Python module or something to find only these numbers? I have tried psutil, but that is not what I want. I am using Linux, a terminal command would work as well. With your answer, please keep it simple, because I am a new programmer.

Comment: If you're using Linux, then reading `/proc/meminfo` would be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the total memory:

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo |grep -oE "[0-9]*"
```

This one free memory:

```
grep MemFree /proc/meminfo |grep -oE "[0-9]*"
```

This one Active memory:

```
grep Active /proc/meminfo |grep -oE "[0-9]*"
```

You can extract all the information you need from **/proc/meminfo** like this.

To see what options do you have, run `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: N.B: `Used=Total-Free`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `free` command with option `-g`. This is will give a snapshot the memory in GB

```
root@x.x.x.x.:~# free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            31         24          6          0          0         14
-/+ buffers/cache:         10         21
Swap:           31          0         31
```